# Are prepositions relative to one another?

Tags: prepositions

Take an instance with some of the most common English prepositions: in, on, at, below, and above.

1. The noun "aircraft" goes with "on", but is the sentence "Parachuters jump off the plane" must be used in this context? Can it go with "out of"?

Comment: What do you mean by "relative to one another"? What do you mean by "is the sentence 'Parachuters jump off the plane' must be used in this context?"

Comment: Prepositions aren't as invariable as you believe. I got *on* the plane—most common. I got *into* the plane—less common, but perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Prototypical usages of prepositions show locative / directional relations between two referents (_The ball_ is on / beside / under / behind / by ... _the table_; _she_ went to / from ... _the station_) or temporal ones (_the speech_ is before / after / during after _the meal_). But increasingly metaphorical to peripheral usages get trickier and more idiosyncratic (he was _on the train_; the shed was _on fire_).

Comment: To reply to Alphabet's comment, I would like to point out that "relative to one another" means prepositions related to other prepositions (antonyms, synonyms, etc). For instance, the opposite of "get onto a plane" is "get off a plane".

Comment: But "get on a plane" and "get out of a plane" are also possible. As Peter says, more variation is possible than you seem to think.

Comment: To summarise what other people have said, although many prepositions come in pairs, such as *on-off*, that doesn't mean that using one preposition of such a pair commits you to using the other. That is fairly obvious, and posting it as a formal answer would be at odds with the practices of this site. If there is anything else you are asking, you may wish to edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: I think there is confusion between phrasal verbs per se versus verbs with a prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 1):

If I get *off* a plane, it means that the plane is on the ground and I am simply disembarking on foot. If I get *out of* a plane, it means that I am using an unconventional method of leaving the plane -- it might be still airborne if I am a parachutist; or it might be on fire and I am using the emergency slide; or it might be (from Kate Bunting's comment) that it's a small plane that you have to climb out of, instead of leaving it on foot.

This mirrors the opposite usage: if I get *on* a plane, I am boarding it in the normal way, on foot. If I get *into* a plane, I am crawling in through a window, or something similar.

So your notion of "relative" prepositions is valid here.

Comment: I would argue that this isn't necessarily true; for instance, if it's the kind of plane where you have to climb out of the cockpit, _out of_ would be a reasonable preposition to use.

Comment: @KateBunting:Yes, I agree. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: For *on* and *into,* particularly with modes of transport, *on* is used for entering a conveyance on foot ("on a plane"; "on a bus"; "on a train"; "on a ship") and *into* when you can't do that ("into a car"). "When you can't do that" also holds true for the first list: "got into a bus" implies you didn't walk on normally. And "he travelled on a car" suggests something different from "he travelled in a car." [This doesn't change your answer, which is entirely correct; but expands it a little.]

Comment: There's definitely a lot of variation. "On the plane" applies to passengers taking a flight, but "in the plane" applies certainly to some inanimate objects, possibly to a pilot in a warplane or a cleaner in an airport, maybe if the plane was an exhibit in a museum, etc.